# Speeding up a NOT NULL query on a text field in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
select count(*) from people where text_field is not null;
```

It's slow. Is it kosher to put an index on mediumtext field? What's the best practice for this?

Comment: I'm always in favor of practical answers and testing. If you just need a null check, try creating an index of length 1 on the field and see what it does for your query. Either the storage engine is following the pointer to each row's text field on disk to see if it's null and you'll get a big improvement, or it was already storing whether a value existed or not in the table and you won't. Remember to flush the query cache between tests.

Comment: Tried that. Adding an index (to a mediumtext field, length 1, innodb) actually increased the query time by 35%.

Comment: @DanGrossman This should be an answer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This `is not null` query predicate is notorious for being impossible to index. That's because null comparisons in SQL work non-intuitively.

Your best bet is to figure out some other way to find these non-empty text_field values. If this query needs to run often, you'll need to store some kind of flag value.

For example, add an INT column called text_field_length and populate it with the length of the text_field, then select where text_field_length > 0

**Edit eight years later**

Newer versions of MySQL (5.7 +) and MariaDB now have computed columns. Those computed columns may be indexed.

So you may add a computed column, maybe called `text_field_not_null`, to your `people` table, and an index on that column.

```
ALTER TABLE people add column text_field_not_null INT
        AS (IF(text_field IS NULL,0,1)) STORED;
CREATE INDEX text_field_not_null_dex ON people(text_field_not_null);
```

Then, this query will exploit that new index.

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE text_field_not_null = 1;
```

And, the value of this new column gets handled automatically.

(MySQL has almost caught up to the pricey table servers in this respect.)

Comment: "For example, add an INT column called text_field_length and populate it with the length of the text_field, then select where text_field_length > 0" --- if there are only few rows with 0 length - it would cause fullscan

Comment: Thanks. I'm using rails so I just made a `before_save` filter that sets a boolean. It does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mysql is an "old tin can", we had to add an auxiliary field of type BOOLEAN with indexing and trigger:

```
IF NEW.text_field='' THEN 
SET NEW.boolean_field = 1;
ELSE
SET NEW.boolean_field = 0;
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

the most efficient is to use, **`HAVING`**

```
select count(*) as Num from people 
HAVING Num is not null;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

You would use this query

```
   select count(*) from people where text_field not like "";
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score -3):

I hope you use this type of query

select count(*) from people where text_field IS NOT NULL;

Please add filter clause so get better performance

Comment: See the already accepted answer for why this solution is not recommended.